# How to use Service in a class that implements OnApplicationShutdown interface in NestJS

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs

The service that I am trying to use is from an external library which has a global fields defined within itself, that I use in different modules.

I've tried to inject the service within a constructor but its value is `undefined` when it is called.

Content of **shutdown.hook.ts**:

```js
export class AppShutdownHook implements OnApplicationShutdown {
    constructor(
        private fooService: FooService
    ) {}

    async onApplicationShutdown(signal: string) {
        if (signal === "SIGTERM") {
            this.fooService.getFooField();
        }
    }
}
```

Content of **main.ts**:

```js
app.enableShutdownHooks();
```

Also, I tried to initialize the service as a class property, but it creates another instance of a Service class, which has different values of global ones.

```js
export class AppShutdownHook implements OnApplicationShutdown {
    private fooService = new FooService();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Is your `AppShutdownHook` marked with `@Injectable()`?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel no, it's not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decorate `AppShutdownHook` with `@Injectable()` so that Nest can read the metadata of the constructor and properly do the Dependency Injection you're expecting.

Comment: Damn, I missed such an obvious thing. Appreciate your help :)